# installation of a php application in a (sub)folder

Tags: php

I'm creating a *Web Application*, and I have the following line in my code:

```
<?php
    define('ROOT',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
?>
```

Everywhere i do an `include()` or so, I use this

```
<?php
    include_once(ROOT.'/path/to/script.php');
?>
```

What's the problem? When I install my application a folder, let's say /demo/ it won't work!

I assume the problem has to do with `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, but I can't figure it out. Where's my fault?

Comment: `define('ROOT',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/demo');`

Comment: yes but the problem is I don't know the map name yet so it has to be dynamic

Answer (score 0):

How can your application work if you install it to `/demo`, but request files from `DOCUMENT_ROOT`?

Either install your application to `DOCUMENT_ROOT` or set your `'ROOT'` constant properly:

```
define('ROOT',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/demo');
```

In case you don't know folder name - use magic constant [`__DIR__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php):

```
define('ROOT', __DIR__);
```